# React/Apollo 2 -- What is the proper way to store auth states?

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I'm not quite sure what the right question to ask is, but I'll describe what it is that I'm trying to do.

Current Methodology:

At the moment in my React App, when a user hits my handleSubmit function, it sends the credentials over to my server side for verification, upon verification it then sends a user object as well as a 200 status code back to my client side. If the client side receives a status 200, I then have a mutation method that's something like updateAuthStatus({ variables: { isAuthed: true }}). If a 400 status is sent, an error alert just pops up.

After the cache is updated, my private routes check against the isAuthed status to render certain components.

The Issue:

If you put a breakpoint at the right spot, you can run the updateAuthStatus command in the console with "true", and it will update the cache and you will then have access to the private routes.

Possible Alternative:

I thought about another way which is to add another column in my database for authenticated users, and this will be set on the server side after the verification process is complete. Then on my client side, it will make a request to check whether or not the user is authenticated before rendering each view.

But this way doesn't seem quite correct as it will have to make a request to the server every single time a new route is pushed ...

To my understanding, there's no real way to prevent your functions from being called in the console and if that's the case, what's the correct way to resolve an issue like this? How should I be checking the authentication status of a user?

I'm using Apollo 2.0 for the state management

Comment: It doesn't really matter if users can trick the browser into rendering a private route. The important thing is that if that route tries to make a request to the server, the server needs to enforce authentication (e.g. not returning or changing data for unauthorized users).

Comment: Hmm, if that's the case, should the flow be to then send credentials to the server, if valid, send a session cookie back to the client, and then store the cookie. Everytime the client pushes to a private route, the private route should then make a request to the server with the cookie  for validation.

Is that a more correct way of doing this?

Comment: You're right that you should use a cookie (or some similar method) for making sure the session is valid. But you don't necessarily need to verify it every time you hit a private route...just every time you call the server to do something.